# Is it natural to say "ladle me some soup please" when I want someone to put some soup into my bowl?

Tags: word-usage

Is it natural to say

> Ladle me some soup please.

when I want someone to put some soup into my bowl? Would be more natural to say

> Ladle some soup into my bowl please?

If neither of those is correct, what would a native English speaker say to communicate the message?

Comment: We would say "May I have some soup, please?" or "Can I please have some soup?" or "I'd like some soup" or "I'll have some soup" or any of a number of things. We would almost never say "Ladle me some soup please," though that construction is not impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not natural to say "ladle me some soup". Though in some very informal AmE situation, one might say it.

Ladle soup into a bowl. = better. But it is still not the best way to ask someone to serve you some soup.

"The volunteers ladled soup into bowls for the people staying at the shelter."

To ladle is to use an instrument called a ladle.

But generally, one would probably say:

**Can you give me some soup? Can you serve me some soup?**

That's because soup is always ladled and it's obvious. Most people do not serve soup by, say, dipping a cup into the soup pan.

If you were writing a description, though, then you would use ladle:

The waiter **ladled the eggnog into a glass** and handed it to the waiting guest.

Any liquid foodstuff can be ladled from a pot or bowl into another receptacle.

If you take other words used with **serving food** (cut, for example), you would **not generally say**: Can you c**ut me a piece of pie**? to a host or person who is serving it.

**You would say:** May I have a piece or cake? May I have a piece of cake, please.

Verbs associated with  ways of serving food (ladling, cutting, lifting [meat off a grill with a fork].etc/) are not usually used when asking for that food.

"Don't dip that cup into the soup to serve it, Johnny. Use the ladle!"